# jquery ui sortable: can't type in input fields with cancel method

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I cannot use **input fields** for typing data anymore after `cancel` method of `sortable` is implemented.

```
$(function() {
            $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
                connectWith: ".connected-sortable",
                cancel: ".not-sortable",
                update: function(){

                // php update...
                }
            });
});​
```

All input fields are working fine **without** `cancel`, any idea how I can get around to this? Or maybe I have done some mistakes in the html code, etc?

Here is the test page -

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VqB2u/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really odd, and probably a bit of a pain.

I figured out a work-around, but it's not the cleanest.

```
$('input').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).trigger({
        type: 'mousedown',
        which: 3
    });
});

$('input').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 3){
        $(this).focus();   
    }
});
```

Basically, in the above, we detect the click. the event still fires, so we trigger the the mousedown and declare the which of 3, which was the right-click, because for some reason right click worked. Then in the mousedown, which we trigger, we detect if it was a right click and if so, we'll focus the element.

Comment: Thanks. where should I put this lines in?

Comment: @lauthiamkok Anywhere in the document's ready function. [Here's the working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VqB2u/1/)

Answer (score 2):

A good solution is to set `handle` option. Would require you to create an extra element within your `LI` that isn't on top of the `input`. This element would act as the drag handle